# I am trying to get a GEOCode and getting this error on R, how do I fix it?

Tags: r, curl, system-calls, geocode

[image: I am trying to get the latitudes and longitudes of these cities]

Tried using Geocode and I dont understand the error or the how to solve it

Comment: geocode is (apparently) a function from a package that you do not appear to have yet loaded. The error is coming from an effort to access something from the Web.

Comment: The libraries that I am using are tidyverse, ggbiplot, plyr and ggrepel. What package do I need for geocode?

Comment: Probably `ggmap` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggmap/versions/2.6.1/topics/geocode